# Space complexity of two recursive functions

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

I've got an interesting case doing LeetCode - I'm not sure what is Space complexity of this function. On the one hand when it calls itself, there are not traverse functions  in the stack, so I believe space complexity is O(n).
But but if the recursion stack is empty should I say that this is not O(n^2) but O(n)?
Any help much appreciated!

```
class Solution {
    int count = 0;
    long targetSum;
    
    public int pathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        this.targetSum = targetSum;
        traverse(root, (long)0);
        pathSum(root.left, targetSum);
        pathSum(root.right, targetSum);
        return count;
    }
    
    private void traverse(TreeNode root, long currSum) {
        if (root == null) return;
        
        if (currSum + root.val == this.targetSum) {
            this.count++;
        }
        
        traverse(root.left, currSum + root.val);
        traverse(root.right, currSum + root.val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Space complexity is indeed O(n). But time complexity is O(n²), so not efficient.

Comment: If we can be certain the tree is balanced, the space complexity is O(log n).  The worst case tree is a list which is O(n)